# In next.js app, how to add a unified request header for all request sent by client or nextjs(getServerSideProps)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-headers, internationalization, middleware

I am internationalizing my nextjs project and would like to add a unified request header, "lang=currentLocales", to all requests I send to the Java backend(or just for those http requests in getServerSideProps function). This way, I can retrieve the current language from the request header and return data for the corresponding language in every request received by the backend. I tried using the middleware,but it seems like getServerSideProps cannot set it automatically in the request. So how can I relize it? I will appreciate it if anyone can answer the question.

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB1ON.png)

I tried using the middleware to add a unified request header, but it seems like the getServerSideProps function can just read it from the parametter passed by the nextjs, but will not add the request header to the request sent to Java-Spring backend automatically.